# Error when uploading JAR to Oracle Integration Cloud Service: Failed to register library

Tags: javascript, soa, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I'm getting the below error whenever I'm trying to upload my executable JAR to an Oracle Integration Cloud instance (library).

`Error: Failed to register library. Library file filename.jar should contain at least one JS file with valid functions.`

My JAR contains logic to convert a txt file to a csv file, it is executing fine from a command prompt.

Let me know if anyone has a solution for this issue.

Comment: Do you maybe have a Java class instead of JavaScript? Java classes are not supported.

Comment: Yes, I have built login in java and created executable jar

Comment: You will need to rewrite your code in JavaScript instead of Java, then use it like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud-service/icsug/using-libraries-manage-functions-integrations.html).

Comment: Thanks, i'll write the logic in JS.

Comment: Have you rewritten it yet? You can use custom Java code in OIC classic user managed. I will type up an answer if interested. But as for the "jar" file, that is a JavaScript archive

Answer (score 0):

OIC does not support custom java functions.Only javascript functions with return types as string,number or Boolean are supported .